# convert javascript document.write results to BBCode format

Tags: javascript, bbcode, document.write

I have a javascript document.write function that returns a textarea value to a field like so:

```
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
   document.write(opener.document.msg.message.value)
</script>
```

Now, I need the output of what is returned from the document.write part to be in BBCode output, so if the value fetched from the document.write function is [b]hello[/b], it returns "**hello**" not [b]hello[/b]. Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Solved with javascript replace() function